# asctec pelican drivers windows

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can i use ros packages for asctec pelican (drivers , mav framework ) on windows

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41521/asctec-pelican-drivers-windows/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Windows is not currently a supported platform.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0